# node.js cache busting techniques

Tags: caching, node.js

When rendering html files that refer to static files (.js, .css) - how do you handle cache busting? do you manually change the blabla.css?v=VERSIONNUMBER everytime you change the file? do you have some automatic mechanism based on file's mtime?

Comment: We achieved this using the simplest way: just add the app's start timestamp as query string for each static resource. Example here: http://ankitjain.info/ankit/2013/12/05/cache-busting-nodejs-express-jade/

Answer (score 7):

I'd leave caching up to the HTTP protocol, as it is designed for that. Just provide an `ETag` response header in each response and add support for conditional requests by checking for `If-none-match` request header.

A good way to calculate an entity tag depends on your way to store files. On a typical *nix filesystem, the inode value is a good start.

Example:

```
fs.stat(filePath, function(err, stats) {
    if (err || !stats.isFile()) {
        //oops
    }
    else {
        var etag = '"' + stats.ino + '-' + stats.size + '-' + Date.parse(stats.mtime) + '"';

        //if etag in header['if-non-match'] => 304
        //else serve file with etag
    }
});
```

In special cases, you might even want to cache the etag or even the file in the memory and register a `fs.watchFile()` callback in order to invalidate the entry as soon as the file changes.

Comment: Thanks. But I take it that some browsers ignore such and such headers  and don't bother to check for 304's if they have the file in their cache.. am I missing how somehow your suggestion still solves this?

Comment: Moreover.. Could FireFox be.. umm.. *lying* to me (via firebug)? In its Net tab I see requests going out to fetch those static files and return with a nice 200 http response, while in _reality_ they don't hit my server or show up in Fiddler (they just get served by the very aggressive local cache) - again please make me understand if i'm missing something.